# CNN: taking the most confident prediction among many

Tags: conv-neural-network, pytorch

I'm training a CNN for image classification. The same object (with the same label then) is present in the test set twice (like two view-point). I'd like to take advantage of this when predicting the class.

Right now the final layer is a `Linear` layer (PyTorch) and I'm using cross-entropy as loss function. I was wondering what is the best way to take the most *confident* prediction for each object. Should I first compute the `LogSoftMax` and take the class with the highest probability (among both arrays of predictions), or should I take the logits directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `LogSoftMax` preserves order, the largest logit will always correspond to the highest confidence. Therefore there's no need to perform the operation if all you're interested in is finding the index of most confident class.

Probably the easiest way to get the index of the most confident class is by using [`torch.argmax`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.argmax).

e.g.

```
batch_size = 5
num_logits = 10
y = torch.randn(batch_size, num_logits)
preds = torch.argmax(y, dim=1)
```

which in this case results in

```
>>> print(preds)
tensor([9, 7, 2, 4, 6])
```

Comment: Thanks. Well, okay then it's useless to use it... I was also wondering if there's a way to combine the two arrays of predictions that actually makes sense to improve the confidence of the network.

Comment: Do you generally have such known pairs during inference or only during training?

Comment: I always know these pairs of images.

Comment: Then one straightforward method is to average the logits of these pairs/tuples before computing the loss function. There are more complex methods but this tends to work surprisingly well in a lot of cases. During inference you would average the logits of known tuples as well.